# How to get description and image of first result from Wikipedia API

Tags: json, wikipedia-api

This is my first post on the community and im not a native english speaker so please pardon me for my bad english and for any mistakes i might do in posting this.

Im creating an application(NodeJS) that will search for a planet name on Wikipedia and return the first result description and image in JSON format.

My Requirements are:

1. Must be in JSON Format;
2. Must be done with only ONE Api Call;

   Of course i searched google and Stackoverflow for a solution , before posting.

By following the Wikipedia API DOC (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch) && (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page)

I tried this query:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=planet%20mars&limit=1&namespace=0&format=json
```

This only gives me The title and the link for the article

If i try the same query but in xml format:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=planet%20mars&limit=1&namespace=0&format=xml
```

As you can see by changing format to xml , it works , i can get the image tag ! But my application won't accept xml format(for security reason) !

How can i get the same result , but in JSON FORMAT ?

Is there any other way of successfully fetching the description and image of a search result from wikipedia ?

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution , so i will answer my own question maybe it might help someone one day
the api call i must use is: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts|pageimages&exintro&explaintext&generator=search&gsrsearch=intitle:planet%20mars&gsrlimit=1&redirects=1